# Gaussian Sum with python

Tags: python, random-walk

I found this code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# We create 1000 realizations with 200 steps each
n_stories = 1000
t_max = 500

t = np.arange(t_max)
# Steps can be -1 or 1 (note that randint excludes the upper limit)
steps = 2 * np.random.randint(0, 1 + 1, (n_stories, t_max)) - 1

# The time evolution of the position is obtained by successively
# summing up individual steps. This is done for each of the
# realizations, i.e. along axis 1.
positions = np.cumsum(steps, axis=1)

# Determine the time evolution of the mean square distance.
sq_distance = positions**2
mean_sq_distance = np.mean(sq_distance, axis=0)

# Plot the distance d from the origin as a function of time and
# compare with the theoretically expected result where d(t)
# grows as a square root of time t.
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
plt.plot(t, np.sqrt(mean_sq_distance), 'g.', t, np.sqrt(t), 'y-')
plt.xlabel(r"$t$")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Instead of doing just steps -1 or 1 , I would like to do steps following a standard normal distribution ... when I am inserting np.random.normal(0,1,1000) instead of np.random.randint(...) it is not working.

I am really new to Python btw.

Many thanks in advance and Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

You are entering a single number as third parameter of `np.random.normal`, therefore you get a 1d array, instead of 2d, see the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html). Try this:

```
steps = np.random.normal(0, 1, (n_stories, t_max))
```